# Json format to Java Object mapping

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

In my Spring boot Project , 
I am getting this Json after hitting a Rest Api as shown below:

```
{
  "policy": {
    "policyNumber": "LIC1233",
    "policyStatus": "Inactive",
    "policyPremiumAmount": 15000
  },
  "paymentType": [
    {
      "cardId": "1",
      "cardNo": "234234234234",
      "cardType": "MasterCard"
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pagination": {
      "offset": 50,
      "limit": 25,
      "previousOffset": 25,
      "nextOffset": 75,
      "currentPage": 3,
      "pageCount": 40,
      "totalCount": 1000
    }
  }
}
```

Now i need to expose this json as a Common Object to another REst endpoint in my Spring boot Project through ResponseEntity.

How shall i form the common Java Object to expose it to another the endpoint? also i would like to know Do i need to create a POJO for each of the parentNode (ex-paymentType)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a pojo, you can also use a map,this would be further nested down the line according to the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [generator](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to map JSON to Java classes. It gives you an idea how you could structure your classes.